# Is displaying the tiles of a 2d game for an editor in seperate pictureboxes even a good idea?

Tags: c#, dictionary, 2d, tiles

So I'm building a map editor for this little game called "Cataclysm". Coding aside (since that isn't really the problem), **Is using a picturebox for each tile even a good idea?**

Do you have any other ideas that make things a little easier on both me and my PC? (Using visual studio there is notable slowdowns when moving or handling all 144 pictureboxes for a 12x12 quadrant of a map file)

Another idea I had is just assembling the picture for a map and then stuffing it in a single picturebox, but how would I edit individual tiles this way? Put a raster over it and check which tile the mouse is on when you click?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Edit: 
This is an editor - not an individual game!

Comment: Is it just the designer that slows down, or the application itself?

Comment: Which framework are you using?  Winforms?  WPF?  XAML?

Comment: Probably not the best idea. There are obviously many ways of doing so, but if you have it working with picture boxes consider keeping it that way till you feel there is nothing else in your game that is more important. (It is also not possible to suggest anything that "easier on you" as it is unclear what your experience and amount of time is )

Comment: I'm using Winforms for this. The Designer is the thing that slows down, the application, when in debug mode, behaves just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I'd say you're best off *not* using individual picture box controls if you can help it. Each of those controls consumes resources and too many can slow down your application.

There is a per-process limit of 10,000 window handles. At this point, you're far from running into or over that limit. But what if you decide to make the map (significantly) larger in a later version of the game? Besides, it isn't good design to come anywhere *close* to the limit. There is also a system-wide limit of 32k, so the more handles consumed by one application (up to its 10k limit), the fewer that are available to other applications.

Just use the form's client area as a drawing surface (you don't need any picture boxes at all). Write code that divides it up into the appropriate segments, and then draw your images in each of those sections. Handle the form's MouseClick event, do a hit test to see where the user clicked, and match that up with one of your segments.

Comment: It's not my game. I'm just messing around with editing map and savefiles, so I'm not worried about it becoming larger. But thanks, I didn't at all think about actually using the form itself!

Answer (score 0):

The 2D isometric games that I'm using makes use of a single picturebox. What I did was I took the mouse X and Y location and divided it by the height and width of the tile. Convert that number to an int (throwing away the decimal values). That should give you the exact tile. But you might need to play with the formula a bit if you don't use the mouse location on the picturebox itself. So on the mouse click event, you get tile that the user clicked on and just paint a new tile image at that location.

If you want to make games using C# why not use XNA? It's a very nice framework and you get lots of tutorials on it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA

http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=23714

http://xnaresources.com/default.asp?page=TUTORIALS

Comment: To put this down here as well, I'm not making a game - I'm making an editor. I'll look into XNA though!